# How to encode URL in Apache mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm now doing it this way:

```
rewriterule ^questions/tagged/(.*) qas.php?q=[$1]
```

Which didn't do encoding stuff yet.

Comment: what is it that you want to happen here?

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what your question actually is asking, but since you know what you're looking for maybe you'll find it in condensed documentation like a [cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/download/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet-v2.pdf).

My guess at answering your question, which I'm uncertain of, is:

```
rewriterule ^questions/tagged/(.*) qas.php?q=[$1] [L]
rewriterule ^qas.php?q=(.*) questions/tagged/[$1] [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to have $1 URL-encoded so it's valid as a query argument? You don't need additional encoding for that, as any character that is valid in the path part is also valid in the query part. So the rule you have there should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `NE` tag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^questions/tagged/(.*) qas.php?q=[$1] [NE]
```